# Simple Complex Conjugate of exponentials

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Often I work with complex exponentials, and I want Mathematica to understand that 
the conjugate of $e^{iHt}$ is $e^{-iHt}$.

Is there a simple way of doing this?  Typically I use the complex-expand function to deal with mathematica not knowing if a variable is real/complex, but this time it returns my output in terms of sins & cosines, which isn't desirable.

Answer (score 4):

```
Simplify[Conjugate[Exp[I h t]], h t ∈ Reals]
(* E^(-I h t) *)
```

`Simplify` can handle this, if the assumption that the exponent is purely imaginary holds. Note that this assumes that the product is real: if each variable is real, you may wish to state that instead:

```
Simplify[Conjugate[Exp[I h t]], {h ∈ Reals, t ∈ Reals}]
```

If `Simplify` takes too long it's also possible that you could consider an equivalent replacement rule:

```
Conjugate[Exp[I h t]] /. Conjugate[h t]->h t
```

However, you'll have to be a bit more careful with this, since the inside term can vary quite a bit based on assumptions, variable ordering, etc.

If you are not certain that $Ht$ is real, then it's not actually necessarily true that $e^{iHt}=e^{-iHt}$.

And if you are *absolutely*, positively, and perfectly certain that the conjugate of an exponential containing `I` is purely imaginary, you can do this:

```
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Conjugate[Exp[x_ /; Not[FreeQ[x, I]]]] := 
    Evaluate[Exp[Conjugate[x]]] /. Conjugate[y_] -> y;
```

That will cause issues in a variety of places, so double check the use case. You will likely need to refine the qualifier (`Not[FreeQ[x,I]]` is almost definitely overzealous).

Comment: This works, but I'm hoping for something even simpler. For me, I /always/ want to assume my variables are real unless I explicitly say that they are real. 
Every time I write e^{i*anything} write in by hand the variables in the exponent that are real. 

Is there any way I can make a function that always simplifies assuming the internal variables are real?

Comment: @StevenSagona: Added a more extreme approach that should also work, but might introduce unexpected errors in complicated expressions.

Comment: So I attempted to run the first part of your answer on my example, and it's not working. Any idea what my mistake is?

CC[A_] := Simplify[Conjugate[A], c t d \[Element] Reals];
probes = d E^(I c t);
CC[probes]

returns:  E^(-I Conjugate[c t]) Conjugate[d]

Comment: If you're doing it that way, you'll probably want to individually define that each variable is real, not just the product: `{c \[Element] Reals, t \[Element] Reals, d \[Element] Reals}`.

Comment: switched it with no luck. This is what I put: Simplify[Conjugate[A], c \[Element] Reals , t \[Element] Reals, 
  d \[Element] Reals];

Comment: @StevenSagona: You need to specify the assumptions as a list, I edited that part of my answer a little bit ago. Instead of `Simplify[Conjugate[A], c [Element] Reals , t [Element] Reals, d [Element] Reals]`, use `Simplify[Conjugate[A], {c [Element] Reals , t [Element] Reals, d [Element] Reals}]`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
TrigToExp[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[E^(I H t)]]]
(*E^(-I H t)*)
```

You might need to add a `Simplify` in some cases. `ComplexExpand`  assumes everything is real automatically.